# Load environment variables into the .railsrc file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, .railsrc

I'm trying to load an environment variable in my `.railsrc` file,

I have defined my `RAIL_UTILS_HOME` env var in my .bash_profile like

```
export RAIL_UTILS_HOME='/Path/to/Rails/utils'
```

This is what I'm trying to do in `.railsrc` to load a default rails template

```
-T -m $RAIL_UTILS_HOME/template.irb
```

However my `$RAIL_UTILS_HOME` var is not being expanded,

Any idea of how to do this correctly ?

Comment: it's just a typo, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to access environment variables via `ENV["RAIL_UTILS_HOME"]` regardles of where you do it, so it must also work in a `.railsrc` file.

since there is no explicit pattern for a `.railsrc` file, i assume that you have something like this in your `.irbrc` file:

```
railsrc_path = File.expand_path('~/.railsrc')
if ( ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || defined? Rails ) && File.exist?( railsrc_path )
  begin
    load railsrc_path
  rescue Exception
    warn "Could not load: #{ railsrc_path }" # because of $!.message
  end
end
```

this will load `~/.railsrc` file when you start up your rails console.

Comment: I put the same in my `~/.irbrc` (from [this post](http://rbjl.net/49-railsrc-rails-console-snippets)), which didn't work. The snippet in [this post](http://ozmm.org/posts/railsrc.html) worked, however.